# using table adapters created by the designer

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

I have finished reading the MS Step by Step ADO.NET 4 Book.  One thing that I am confused about is, from what I understand you can add a data source to a project and add table adapters from the data source onto a form (or I assume instantiate them in code?) and code with them like you would manually:

```
    Dim Cmd As New SqlCommand(CmdStr, Conn)
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dt As DataTable = Nothing
    da.SelectCommand = Cmd
    Try
        da.Fill(ds, "Data")
        dt = ds.Tables("Data")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error: " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Your Application")
    Finally
        Cmd.Dispose()
    End Try
```

My question is, are you able to code with them like the above, or should you not do that and only use the methods that you have defined in the designer, EG:

```
Me.RenewalTableAdapter.Fill(Me.TestingDBDataSet.Transaction)
```

Reason why I am asking, is that, I need to do date calculations, and the designer does not seem to support date functions:

```
 Dim CmdStr as string = “SELECT DATEPART(year, yourDateColumn) AS eYear FROM YourTable”
```

Comment: In my experience, TableAdapters cause way more problems than they fix.  I'll only use them in situations where I just need to do a simple select to display data. I much prefer the method in your first example in some situations, and DataReaders in most other situations. It may take longer to code and perhaps be more likely to lead to coding errors, but at least you know the data is doing exactly why you're telling it to do.